# Multi part JSON form data json without disabling bodyParser

Tags: next.js

I am learning Next.js - I am trying to read a json file in my backend. All the articles I look up are saying to disable `bodyParser` and using libs like `multer` or `Formidable`. However I am able to read the string clearly when I `console.log` it, is there a way to read this data without a library?

### Here is my code

#### My frontend uploads a json file like this:

```
<input
  type="file"
  onChange={async e => {
      const body = new FormData();
      body.append('english', e.target.files[0]);

      const res = await fetch(`/api/shaykh/english/add`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body
      });
  }}
/>
```

#### Then my api route handles it like this:

```
async function handler(req, res) {
  console.log('body:', req.body.toString());

  res.status(201).json({});
}
```

#### When I do this, the `console.log` properly shows the content of the json file:

```
body: -----------------------------46599061531564325452179919310
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="english"; filename="en-US.json"
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "mainSearch": "hi"
}
```